# How do I generate a dynamic config module that depends on a message defined in the same package?

Tags: ros, catkin, message-generation, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
add_message_files(DIRECTORY msg FILES SensorLevels.msg)
generate_messages()
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(cfg/Camera1394.cfg)
catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS dynamic_reconfigure message_runtime etc...)
```

The build fails the first time, like this:

```
Errors     << camera1394:make /home/joq/ros/ws/logs/camera1394/build.make.009.log                
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joq/ros/ws/src/camera1394/cfg/Camera1394.cfg", line 37, in <module>
    from camera1394.msg import SensorLevels
ImportError: No module named msg
make[2]: *** [/home/joq/ros/ws/devel/.private/camera1394/include/camera1394/Camera1394Config.h] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/camera1394_gencfg.dir/all] Error 2
```

Running the build again succeeds. Somehow, I need to force gencfg to wait on message generation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278089/how-do-i-generate-a-dynamic-config-module-that-depends-on-a-message-defined-in-the-same-package?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2017-12-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need to add an explicit dependency in CMake between the two steps to ensure that the message generation happens before the `.cfg` file is being invoked.

`dynamic_reconfigure` uses the `OUTPUT` signature a `add_custom_command` which is not a CMake target and can therefore not easily be dependent on. I think `generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options` would need to support an optional parameter to pass the expected header file `<somewhere>/include/camera1394/Camera1394Config.h` here: https://github.com/ros/dynamic_reconfigure/blob/17e1d4bf6a538d2def097a7f70b139ccd41e9f78/cmake/dynamic_reconfigure-macros.cmake#L58

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-12-23**:
Thanks, Dirk. I suspected that was the case, but wanted to ask before giving up on that approach.